# Setting table's amount of rows to specific entity

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to set the numberOfRowsInSection: of my table view controller to the amount of items in a specific core data entity's attribute. For example, I have a string saved in core data in an attribute for every cell and I would like the same amount cell's as strings. I then have another attribute in the entity that contains an image for every cell. Because of the two attributes, I would like to set the amount of cell's to the amount of stings, not to the amount of objects in the entity. If I did it based on the amount of objects in the entity, I would have twice the amount of cells that I need. I have a way that I am trying to do this, but the table isn't creating any cells. My problem is no cells are currently being created with this `numberOfRowsInSection:` How would I either fix this code so that the cells appear?

Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"FeedEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"urlString"]];

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO]];
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    // Execute the fetch.
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (objects == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }


    id  sectionInfo =
    [[theFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}
```

Comment: Tell us what problem you're having, rephrase as a question please.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see if `[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]` is more than 0.

Comment: Here I updated my question. My problem is that no cells are being created. @greg

Comment: So it says `CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0041s for 5 rows.` So doesn't that mean that five rows are being created. None of them are showing up though. @Putz1103

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that instead of saving both objects to core data at the same time, I had two methods to save them, one for the string and one for the image. I just condensed them into one method and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

<s>So long as all of your attribute names are correct, I don't inherently see anything wrong with your `numberOfRowsInSection:` implementation. Where you check `objects` for `nil`,  you should also check `error` for `!= nil` to see if CoreData created an error. Since you're not getting what you expect from this method, you might be getting an error.</s>

You're fetching only the `urlString` property but sorting by `timeStamp`. Contrary to what I wrote before, that is inherently wrong. With `selectDistinctResults`, you can't sort by a property you don't fetch. That could be your problem.

Other thoughts might be that `numberOfObjects` is actually zero, due to you not saving any inserted data in CoreData or `sectionInfo` being `nil`. You might not have the `dataSource` property of your `UITableView` wired in correctly and so this method isn't getting called.

You might also consider externalizing your `NSFetchedResultsController` and using `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to be called from `numberOfRowsInSection:`. That way you immediately get updates when new entries are added or deleted.

Comment: So the `numberOfRowsInSection:` is defiantly being called because if I change it back to just getting all objects from the entity, it works, just with twice the amount of cells that I need. If you know a different way of doing this, that would be fine.

Comment: Hey, I thought that the selectDistinctResults could be a problem but how would I sort. (urlString) contains data.

Comment: One more thing, So before I added this last attribute to core data (the extra attribute is why there are extra cells) I already had two attributes, now that I look at timeStamp. And before, although I had two attributes including timeStamp, it was giving me the right amount of cells.

Comment: Are you saying you added an attribute and now you have duplicate cells? I would think you'd want to just add that attribute to existing objects. I'm missing something. As far as sorting, since all you're doing is counting the number of objects, there's no need to sort at all. You could set a `predicate`, maybe where your `timeStamp != NULL`. Not sure exactly what I'm missing here, but it sounds like you're on the right track. Remember, CoreData is an object model, not a relational database.

Comment: Ok so I have one entity with two attributes, one where I save an image and another where I save a string. Each cell should have one string and one image and it should create the right amount of cells. My problem is that say I add one cell with an image and the string, it makes two cells, one with the image and string like it is supposed to plus one that is blank. I am assuming that this is because it is created one cell for the image and another for the string, even though I need one cell for both

Comment: Each object should have both attributes, then you could just count the number of objects of that entity type. Sounds like you're creating an object and saving the string only, then another object and saving the image only. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: So I fixed the problem, I was saving the string in one method and the image in another. After condensing the two, it works perfectly!